# Typescript - properties a and b how to exist or unexist at the same time

Tags: typescript, properties

```
function test(obj) {

}
```

in param obj, it can have properites 'a'、'b' and 'c', like `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`, how to use typescript to define if pass 'a' also need to pass 'b', if not pass 'a' also not pass 'b' in params

Anybody can answer this question for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following type

```
const foo = (obj: { c: number } | {  a: number, b: number, c: number }) => {};
```

Note: You might have to add enable `"strictNullChecks": true,` in your tsconfig.json file

If you cant enable strictNullChecks, you can use this

```
const foo = (obj: { c: number, a?: null, b?: null} | {  a: number, b: number, c: number }) => {};
```

The later states both `a` and `b` must be numbers or both `a` and `b` must be `null/undefined`

Answer (score 0):

This is best modeled by creating a new interface with `a` and `b` and making that an optional parameter in the original object:

```
interface Foo {  a: number, b: number }

interface Bar {
  foo?: Foo
  c: number
}
```

Now, this is valid ts:

```
bar1: Bar = { c: 3 };
bar2: Bar = { foo: { a: 1, b: 2 }, c: 3};
```

But this will throw transpilation errors:

```
// INVALID TS >>>
bar1: Bar = { foo: { a: 1 }, c: 3}
bar2: Bar = { foo: { b: 2 }, c: 3}
```

Semantically, this makes more sense since what you are saying is that two properties are constrained together.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(obj: { a: number, b: number, c: number } | { a?: never, b?: never, c: number }) {}

test({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
test({ c: 1 });
```