# Typescript: Ensure a type has a property A if it also has property B

Tags: typescript

I have a type that looks like something as follows:

```js
type MyType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c?: number;
  d?: string;
}
```

There are objects of this type which can look like:

```js
const myObj1: MyType = { a, b };
const myObj2: MyType = { a, b, c, d };
```

So if an object of `MyType` has the property `c`, it will definitely have property `d`.  Is there a way to define this type as such that I do not have to non-null assert or check for both types other than extending the type into a different type?

Comment: *other than extending the type into a different type?* Do you mean you don't want to modify the definition of `MyType`?

Comment: I didn't want to have something like: `MyType` for `a` and `b`, and `MyType2` for all `a,b,c,d` because then I would have to modify other types as well as side effects. Your answer works for me I think. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - properties a and b how to exist or unexist at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937736/typescript-properties-a-and-b-how-to-exist-or-unexist-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're allowed to change `MyType`, one approach is to separate the `c` and `d` properties into a different object where they're required, and alternate with an intersection with that object.

```
type AB = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
};
type MyType = AB | AB & {
    c: number;
    d: string;
}
```

This way, if something of MyType is seen to have a `c` property, TypeScript will see that it definitely also has a `d` property.

Comment: How would I check if an object of `MyType` is of type `AB` or the second `&` type? Currently it is defaulting to `AB` and giving me an error in the `if` statement I check if such an object has `c` such as `if(myObj.c)`

Comment: Before narrowing, it should be seen only as `MyType`, which is the union. To narrow without TS errors, you can use `if ('c' in myObj)`

Comment: Right. `if ('c' in myObj)` works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want property 'd' to exist only when 'c' is defined and vice-versa, it would be worth using `extended` interfaces and overwriting the optional properties as `never` as follows:

```
type Base = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c?: number;
  d?: string;
} 

interface Concrete1 extends Base {
  c?: never;
  d?: never;
}
    
interface Concrete2 extends Base {
  c: number;
  d: string;
}

type MyType = Concrete1 | Concrete2;

const myObj1: MyType = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }; 
const myObj2: MyType = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 2 }; ❌
const myObj3: MyType = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 2, d: 'd' };
```

This will ensure that an object of `MyType` always contains either `a, b` or `a,b,c,d` properties.

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgpTgLigWACcBLAOwHMBubXAI0OPOrpygGMB%20QigVwC2DCCXa4AJryKlKtbAF8o2bJWCiAZnE7QAwgHsKnEhHUBGKBAAe6ihISxE0TBx58IAN1HioU917FFelxlLDVNbT1DY1MIACZLGwg7B3gkdGDOPiERQI4JZlk2IKxsUEgoAFkQABVwFCgDIxNzKAAfRuiW%20PZsTkNiKEEQAHkGACszQmq6itQ0PEIAcjglgBooJiglhiWoBXZ%20ikHhsfG46dr6qHnF7dWNrZ31rkIEg76B4CHRiYBmS6zBoLAj3F5PXYbLJQOIbArbCR7D5YIA).